# How to handle meta_url in django CMS, it's not a configurable parameter in django CMS portal

Tags: django, meta-tags, django-cms

As **meta-url** is not configurable, the new pages that are duplicating the existing pages are holding the same `meta_url` of the parent page.

How to make meta_url a configurable parameter in django CMS ? 
Is there any work around to handle `meta_url` ?

Comment: What do you mean by `meta_url`? Do you have an example of some sort?

Comment: Is a custom meta_tag that we introduced in my site pages.I just curious to know do have an option to select any field to be shown in page-tags ?

Comment: You'd have to post some code for anybody to be able to help. If it's custom, only you know what it is until you share some code.